# Electron API not working after keyCode function added

Tags: api, electron

Electron API is not working.
I'm getting the following error. I see that the sendPin function is not working.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendPin')
    at HTMLDocument.handlekeyUp (pin-pad:86:28)
pin-pad:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendPin')
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (pin-pad:61:28)
```

It was working until I had added following line of code, for this reason I suspect it may be the main reason.

```
if (13 === e.keyCode) { window.electronAPI.sendPin(Pin);
```

index.html is as following.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pinpad.css" />

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Electron Test - Pin Pad</title>
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <input type="password" id="display" disabled />

        <div id="pin-pad">
          <div data-number="1">1</div>
          <div data-number="2">2</div>
          <div data-number="3">3</div>
          <div data-number="4">4</div>
          <div data-number="5">5</div>
          <div data-number="6">6</div>
          <div data-number="7">7</div>
          <div data-number="8">8</div>
          <div data-number="9">9</div>
          <div>Enter</div>
          <div data-number="0">0</div>
          <div>Clear</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    let display = document.getElementById("display");
    let validKeys = [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7",
      "8",
      "9",
      "0",
      "Enter",
      "Clear",
    ];
    let pin = "";

    document.getElementById("pin-pad").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      if (!validKeys.includes(event.target.innerText)) {
        return;
      }

      if (event.target.innerText === "Enter") {
        window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin);
        return;
      }

      if (event.target.innerText === "Clear") {
        pin = display.value = "";
        return;
      }

      pin = pin + event.target.innerText;
      display.value = "*".repeat(pin.length);
    });

    ///tests
    const handlekeyUp = function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();

      const input = document.getElementById("display");
      console.log(input, e.key, input.value);
      var reg = new RegExp("^[0-9]$");
      const number = document.querySelector(`[data-number="${e.key}"]`);

      if (reg.test(e.key)) input.value += e.key;
      if (number) number.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
      if (13 === e.keyCode) {
        window.electronAPI.sendPin(Pin);
      }
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
      const number = document.querySelector(`[data-number="${e.key}"]`);
      if (!number) {
        return;
      }
      number.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
    };

    document.addEventListener("keyup", handlekeyUp);

    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  </script>
</html>
```

main.js

```js
const electronApp = require("electron").app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require("electron").BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require("electron").ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
  const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
    fullscreen: true,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  window.loadFile("pin-pad.html").then(() => {
    window.show();
  });

  return window;
}

electronApp.on("ready", () => {
  window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    electronApp.quit();
  }
});

electronApp.on("activate", () => {
  if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on("pin", (event, pin) => {
  // Simple check of pin validity
  if (pin === "1234") {
    window.loadFile("sales.html");
  }
});
```

preload.js is as following, I have also added just incase.

```js
const contextBridge = require("electron").contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
  sendPin: (pin) => {
    ipcRenderer.send("pin", pin);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to `index.html`, within the `if (13 === e.keyCode) { ... }` statement, the argument of the `window.electronAPI.sendPin(...);` call is of the incorrect case. Instead of `Pin`, it should be `pin`.

That said, `pin` is not updated within your `const handlekeyUp = function (e) { ... }` function, so when "Enter" (or "Return") is pressed, it can't send an updated `pin` to your render process.

Looking closer at your JavaScript code contained within your `index.html` file:

1. There would be no need to stop event propagation.
2. Regex's can be tricky things and hard to implement at times. Only use them if you really need to.
3. It appears that you are use the `#display` value instead of using the already defined `pin` variable to build your `pin`.

Continuing to use the already defined `pin` variable allows you to use both the mouse and the keyboard together (if the user really wants to) to enter a pin.

Use of [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)  is a smart way to standardize key pin-pad input. Extending this idea to the "Enter" and "Clear" buttons would be a great idea. Converting the data-attribute value to lower case and comparing against a valid list of keys is still the way to go. Adding a shortcut for the "Clear" button `c` can work as well. PS: `esc` could also be implemented to clear the display.

Lastly, instead of manually adding and removing the depressed button background color via Javascript, use Javascript to add and remove a CSS class name containing the color. Keeping CSS settings within your style sheet(s) allows for good code separation and easy of debugging. PS: Sometimes, people add a `js-` prefix to their CSS class names that are toggled / controlled by Javascript.

---

Below, I have added an additional `hover` / `js-depressed` class to your CSS to cover mouse and keyboard user feedback.

`pinpad.css` (render process)

```css
#pin-pad div:hover,
#pin-pad div.js-depressed {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

---

Below, I took the liberty to rework your `index.html` Javascript a little bit to remove unnecessary lines of code and simplify the implementation of keyboard (along with mouse) implementation.

> Even more refactoring could be performed to keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) if you wanted to.

Keeping your code as simple as possible makes for easy to read / debug code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pinpad.css"/>

        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Electron Test - Pin Pad</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <input type="text" id="display" disabled/>

                <div id="pin-pad">
                    <div data-key="1">1</div>
                    <div data-key="2">2</div>
                    <div data-key="3">3</div>
                    <div data-key="4">4</div>
                    <div data-key="5">5</div>
                    <div data-key="6">6</div>
                    <div data-key="7">7</div>
                    <div data-key="8">8</div>
                    <div data-key="9">9</div>
                    <div data-key="enter">Enter</div>
                    <div data-key="0">0</div>
                    <div data-key="clear">Clear</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        let display = document.getElementById('display');
        let validKeys = [
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '4',
            '5',
            '6',
            '7',
            '8',
            '9',
            '0',
            'enter',
            'clear',
            'backspace'
        ];
        let pin = "";

        // Mouse input
        document.getElementById('pin-pad').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            let key = event.target.dataset.key;

            if (! validKeys.includes(key)) {
                return;
            }

            if (key === 'enter') {
                window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin);
                return;
            }

            if (key === 'clear') {
                pin = display.value = "";
                return;
            }

            pin = pin + key;
            display.value = '*'.repeat(pin.length);
        });

        // Keyboard input
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            let key = event.key.toLowerCase();

            if (! validKeys.includes(key)) {
                return;
            }

            if (key === 'backspace') {
                pin = pin.slice(0, -1);
                display.value = "*".repeat(pin.length);
                return;
            }

            document.querySelector(`[data-key="${key}"]`).classList.add('js-depressed');

            if (key === 'enter') {
                window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin);
                return;
            }

            pin = pin + key;
            display.value = '*'.repeat(pin.length);
        });

        document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
            let key = event.key.toLowerCase();

            if (! validKeys.includes(key) || key === 'backspace') {
                return;
            }

            document.querySelector(`[data-key="${key}"]`).classList.remove('js-depressed');
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

> One this not taken into account if de-bouncing. IE: If the user holds their finger on a key, the input will repeat at a rapid rate fill the pin field. If this behavior is not desired then a "de-bouncing" function may wish to be added.

Comment: @erhan If this answer was helpful, you can upvote it. If this answer was correct, you can mark it as accepted. Don't forget to do it for all questions you have asked in the past and questions you ask in the future. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Comment: The backspace/ Return key is not working :(

Comment: @erhan I can update the answer to reflect "backspace" & "return" key functionality. Will "backspace" functionaility be replacing the "c" key functonality? Additionally, is the "backspace" key supoose to remove one character or all characters from the `#display` (like the "clear" button)? The "return" key may issue a different code than the "enter" key. I only have 2 "enter" keys on my keyboard. To test, place `console.log(key);` just after the `let key = event.key.toLowerCase();` line in the `keydown` event listener code block. Look at the browser console for the result and comment back to me.

Comment: I have checked, return is "enter" on my mac so I believe it's fine. I have actually changed the "c" to "backspace", so it2s kind of fine, but I prefer if it could just delete the last character.

Comment: Updated answer. Changed "c" back to "clear" (for mouse input clarification). Added "backspace" to `validKeys` array. "backspace' is only used for keyboard input.. On backspace, remove last digit in pin `pin.slice(0, -1)`, update `#display` and `return`.

Comment: It didn't work, Backspace is not working at all now.:( `display.value = "*", is a star, since input type is password, other than seeing stars I see round dots. `        <input type="password" id="display" disabled />`

Comment: Change input type to text.

Comment: I tried that didn't work either :8

Comment: Swapped order of key detection in `keydown` event listener and moved `querySelector`  to after `backspace` logic. Fixed error in re-allocating `pin` upon `slice`. And finally, added `backspace` to early bail for `keyup` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.electronAPI.sendPin(Pin); --> window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin);
```

[image]